# How the cursor jump to the next line after inserting date in google doc?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I want to create a script which inserts todays date and jump to the next line. I was able to insert todays date, but cannot jump the cursor to the next line.  Here is the code I've tried.
The error says, "The parameters(String,number) don't match the method signature for DocumentApp.Document.newPosition". But I thought I provide string and number as parameters. Any ideas how to solve this error?

```
function insertAtCursor() {  
  var cursor = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getCursor();
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();  
  
  if (cursor) {
    var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "yyyy-MM-dd"); 
    var text = date.toString();
    var element = cursor.insertText(date);   
    if (element) {
      element.setBold(true);
      element.setForegroundColor("#008000")
    } else {
      DocumentApp.getUi().alert('Cannot insert text at this cursor location.');
    }
  } else {
    DocumentApp.getUi().alert('Cannot find a cursor in the document.');
  }
  
  var position = doc.newPosition(text, text.length); 
  doc.setCursor(position);   
}
```

Comment: @RafaGuillermo Why you removed [tag:javascript] ? The error message is about not using the correct data types and that is something related to JavaScript. Please add it back.

Comment: @Rubén `The parameters don't match the method signature for X` is an Apps Script error, not JavaScript. This is purely a GAS issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224331/discussion-between-ruben-and-rafa-guillermo).

Comment: There are already two answers. If you need further help please add a demo/test document structure, i.e. tell us if the  contains only paragraphs or it contains other element types like list items, tables, etc. and if the date will always be added before the last element.

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer:

*The method signature for [`Document.newPosition()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#newPosition(Element,Integer)) is `Element, Integer`.*

#### Code fix:

Change:

```
var position = doc.newPosition(text, text.length);
```

to:

```
var position = doc.newPosition(element, text.length);
```

#### References:

- [Class Document | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document)

Comment: Hi Rafa, this solved the error but still the cursor is at the end of the date. Do you know how can the cursor jump to the beginning of the next line?

Comment: @Marlowe Is the date being inserted at the end of the line?

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs because the first argument of `newPosition` should be an [Element](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/element) object, not a `string`.

By the other hand if you want to grab the next line you should not use the same *element* (in this case the date) but the one corresponding to the next line. One way to to do this is by usin [getNextSibling](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/element#getnextsibling). In this case I'm using `getParent` in order to get the paragraph containing the inserted date, the use `getNextSibling` to get the next paragraph.

```
function insertAtCursor() {  
  var cursor = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getCursor();
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();  
  
  if (cursor) {
    var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "yyyy-MM-dd"); 
    var element = cursor.insertText(date);   
    if (element) {
      element.setBold(true);
      element.setForegroundColor("#008000")
    } else {
      DocumentApp.getUi().alert('Cannot insert text at this cursor location.');
    }
  } else {
    DocumentApp.getUi().alert('Cannot find a cursor in the document.');
  }
  var par = element.getParent();
  var position = doc.newPosition(par.getNextSibling(), 0); 
  doc.setCursor(position);   
}
```

Another way is to get the child number the, use the next child. A complete solution should consider cases like the date being inserted at the end of the document, inside of table, among others.

SIDENOTE:

You don't have to use `date.toString()` as `Utilities.formatDate` already return a string.